# HBase WAL replication - Is WAL replication from cluster with HBase 1.1.2 to cluster with HBase 2.0.2 supported?

Tags: hbase, replication, wal

Is HBase WAL replication from cluster with HBase 1.1.2 to cluster with HBase 2.0.2 supported ? Tried a simple test where following table was created in both the clusters

```
create 'repl_test', { NAME => 'cf1', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '1'}
```

When issued `enable_table_replication 'repl_test'` to enable replication got following error message, which doesn't seems to be correct given that i have used exactly the same create statement mentioned above for creating the tables in both the clusters.

> ERROR: Table repl_test exists in peer cluster 1, but the table
> descriptors are not same when comapred with source cluster. Thus can
> not enable the table's replication switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from Hbase user forum. Replication from hbase1 to hbase2 is supported. Issue is due to HBASE-24354, which is fixed in 2.3.0